# What's the data type used by navigation stacks in the navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

> A navigation controller object manages the currently displayed screens
>   using the **navigation stack**, which is represented by an array of view
>   controllers.

[image]

The quote and the figure are both come from the Apple [official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller). The quote mentioned the words **navigation stack** while the figure actually points **NSArray** to the Navigation stack.

And this description starts to make me feel confused

> The first view controller in the array is the root view controller.
>   The last view controller in the array is the view controller currently
>   being displayed

The quote describes the characteristics which belong to the stack data type, plus, they do have the **push segue** existing in the StoryBoard. seems UINavigationController do use the stack data type rather than the array/NSArray data type.

**Question 1**

What exactly is the data structure used by the navigation stack of the navigation controller, **Stack** or **Array**?

**Question 2**

What is the difference between topViewController and rootViewController in navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**
ViewControllers attribute is defined as NSArray in `UINavigationController` definition, but have stack behaviours like popViewController method and pushViewController method but you can also modify your ViewControllers array passing a new Array ViewControllers array

> ```
> @property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *>*viewControllers; // The current view controller stack.
> ```

**2 Examples of Stack Behaviour Methods**

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
//Others
- (nullable UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
//Others
```

**But you can also set your ViewControllers array using this method**

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

**Question 2**

`TopViewController` is the current viewController you're seeing and the `rootViewController` is the firstViewController has been added to your navigation stack

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad to help you @SLN

Answer (score 1):

Your first Question's answer is NavigationStack uses **Array Representation** of Stack Data Structure. I think there are two representation of Stack, one is array and other is linked list.
So **push** and **pop** operations are performed using Array here by using :-

```
pushViewController(_:animated:)
popViewController(animated:)
```

Your Second Question's Answer - *TopViewController* of navigation controller represents the view controller at the top of the stack and RootViewController is the first viewcontroller on the Stack

Hope this helps!.

Comment: @Aditay Srivastava Yes, it does help a lot, Thx!